# How to fix NX storybook error in run process?

Tags: angular

I tried to run story book in [NX](https://nx.dev/getting-started/intro):

nx run table:storybook

I got this error:

> NX   Broken build, fix the error above.

You may need to refresh the browser.

> NX   Ran target storybook for project table (12s)

```
×    1/1 failed
√    0/1 succeeded [0 read from cache]
```

How to fix it?